# How to fix Permission denied in python?

Tags: django, amazon-ec2, centos7

I am trying to access index.html from apache configuration.
my apache config is

```
Listen 8080
#ServerName localhost
WSGISocketPrefix /var/run/wsgi

<VirtualHost *:8080>
WSGIDaemonProcess   <group-name> python-path=/opt/codebase/git/.pyenv/versions/3.5.2/envs/<project>/lib/python3.5/site-packages user=apache group=<group-name> display-name=%{GROUP}
WSGIProcessGroup    <group-name> 
WSGIScriptAlias     /api /codebase/projects/<project>/src/apps/apps/wsgi.py process-group=<group-name> 

Timeout 1800

SSLEngine off
SSLCertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/apache.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/pki/tls/private/apache.key


DocumentRoot /codebase/projects/<project>/src/client/<project>

<Directory /codebase/projects/<project>/src/client/<project>>
    Require all granted
    <IfModule expires_module>
        ExpiresActive On
        ExpiresDefault "modification plus 2 seconds"
        # ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 day"
        ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 month"
        ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 month"
    </IfModule>

    Header set Content-Security-Policy "default-src 'self'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'; connect-src 'self'; img-src 'self' data:; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; font-src 'self'; child-src 'self'; form-action 'self'; media-src 'self'; object-src 'self'; report-uri /api/csp/report"
</Directory>
<Directory /codebase/projects/<project>/src/files>
Require all granted
</Directory>
```

I am using centos 7 and apache2.4

I am getting:

```
13) Permission denied: [client 3.204.115.205:64720] AH00035: access to /index.html denied (filesystem path 
'/codebase/projects/<project>/src/client/<project>/index.html') because search permissions are missing on a component of the path.
```

I gave full permission from parent most dir to file. but getting permission denied problem. can some one help me. I am running all this env in EC2 instance.

Comment: Do you have SELinux running? Try this: `sudo setenforce 0` and then restart apache. If this works, DO NOT leave it like this. Turn SELinux back on with: `sudo setenforce 1` and I'll post some links on how to create rules to allow apache access to  those files.

Comment: hi thanks for suggestion i checked the sudo setenforce 0 worked perfectly.

Comment: can you please  add a right way to write the poicy file.  Thanks a lot for suggestion.

Comment: but i got  client denied by server configuration: /codebase/projects/<project./src/apps/apps/wsgi.py now

Comment: Had some configure problem all resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primary solution .

Do you have SELinux running? Try this: sudo setenforce 0 and then restart apache. If this works, DO NOT leave it like this. Turn SELinux back on with: sudo setenforce 1 and I'll post some links on how to create rules to allow apache access to those files. by    – wholevinski